# jQuery Ajax call not matching the Controller parameters even after Json.Stringify()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong here?  I have followed the standard approach to call an MVC controller from a View using jQuery with $.ajax request. I have also matched the names of the Model with parameters. 
 This is my controller and it is getting hit when invoking the ajax call but getting null values in parameter:

```
    [HttpPost, Route("GetUserSettingsTable")]
    public ActionResult GetUserSettingsTable(List<UserSettingsTable> userSettings)
    {
        return PartialView("_UserSettingsTable.cshtml", userSettings);
    }
```

This is the script file I'm using:

```
    var selectedUser = $('#Employees_SelectedValue').val();
    var selectedCountries = $('#Countries_SelectedValue').val();
    var selectedSourceSystems = $('#SourceSystems_SelectedValue').val();
    var userSettings = [];
    for (var i = 0, max = Math.max(selectedCountries.length, selectedSourceSystems.length); i < max; i++)
    {
        userSettings.push({
            UserName: selectedUser,
            UserCountry: selectedCountries[i] || "",
            UserSourceSystem: selectedSourceSystems[i] || ""
        });
    };

    //Here userSettings has values like: [{"121", "AU", "ABC"}, {"121", "IN", "PQR"}, {"121", "NZ", "XYZ"}]

    $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("GetUserSettingsTable", "Admin")',
         type: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify(userSettings),
        success : function (result)
        {
            $('#userSettingsTable').html(result);
        },
        error: function (result)
        {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

Also I have the Models defined as below:

```
public class UserSettingsTable
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string UserCountry { get; set; }

        public string UserSourceSystem { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm unable to find where is the mismatch because when I'm calling the controller it is getting null inthe parameter value. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you use `JSON.stringify(..)` then you also need to include `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: I don't know why this happened, but on my test environment type: "POST", worked fine. However on my production server it broke - type: "POST" would not work. I'm actually still curious why. But try type: "post", will perhaps work for you.

Answer (score 0):

remove JSON.stringify() from data,

```
$.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("GetUserSettingsTable", "Admin")',
     type: "POST",
     data: userSettings,
    success : function (result)
    {
        $('#userSettingsTable').html(result);
    },
    error: function (result)
    {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is and don't just post code. It won't really help the person who asked the question if you don't explain the problem.